# How do I script an undo operation in an Eclipse plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, undo

I'm making a plug-in for Eclipse and I want to leverage the built-in Eclipse 'Undo' action (org.eclipse.core.commands.operations) whenever a user presses the undo button associated with the plug-in.

Ideally, it would just reproduce what happens when you press CTRL+Z, but I didn't get simulating keypresses working.

I've tried these code snippets:

Undo performed in a workbench:

```
IWorkbenchOperationSupport operationSupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getOperationSupport();
IUndoContext context = operationSupport.getUndoContext();
IOperationHistory operationHistory = operationSupport.getOperationHistory();    
IStatus status = operationHistory.undo(context, null, null);
```

Undo performed in a workspace:

```
IWorkbenchOperationSupport operationSupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getOperationSupport();
IUndoContext context= (IUndoContext)ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getAdapter(IUndoContext.class);
IOperationHistory operationHistory = operationSupport.getOperationHistory();
IStatus status = operationHistory.undo(context, null, null);
```

What I am then looking for, analogously, is this, but it doesn't work:

Undo performed on editor/document:

```
IWorkbenchOperationSupport operationSupport = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getOperationSupport();
IEditorPart currentEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
IUndoContext context = (IUndoContext) currentEditor.getAdapter(IUndoContext.class);
IOperationHistory operationHistory = operationSupport.getOperationHistory();
IStatus status = operationHistory.undo(context, null, null);
```

Comment: I'm working on this issue as well.  I've found this examples feature (org.eclipse.sdk.examples.feature) using this update site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2), and it has a nice implementation working just fine. I just need to figure out how to get my view part to take part in the IUndoContext so the undo and redo actions show up in the Eclipse Undo and Redo menu items.  The weird thing is that my undo redo actions work fine only when the sample view part is active, and not when my view part is active.  I guess I don't fully understand IUndoContext yet.

Comment: When trying to install the Eclipse SDK Examples using the Install New Software dialog, use the filter box and type 'Examples' but be sure to uncheck the Group Items by Category or you will see no results.

Comment: For this approach to work you should perform all changes in your editor by adding undoable commands to operation stack.

Answer (score 1):

If your editor has a viewer on it (e.g. TextViewer, SourceViewer, ProjectionViewer), then you can add an undo action that calls the undo operation on the viewer, e.g.

```
Action undoAction = new Action()
{
  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    getViewer().doOperation( ITextOperationTarget.UNDO );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but I think this may be something for you: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t80577.html#92048329

It is a bit outdated but the idea is still not bad.

Comment: I'd really prefer to use Eclipse's built-in package (org.eclipse.core.commands.operations).  I've read many, many examples online that claim this package is ideal for implementing this functionality.  I have successfully added a class which implements IUndoableOperation and am able to execute() the actions, however I cannot seem to make the undo() work...?